# List wordpress categories by alphabet

Tags: php, wordpress

On a category archive page I want to list all the categories so that it looks like this:

> "a"
>
> - ---apple
> - ---answer
>
> "b"
>
> - ---ball
> - ---big
>
> and so on.

This is wordpress I am talking about.

Comment: Three questions: 

Are you using the 'parent' category ability of WordPress, and if so, do you want that relationship to be ignored in order to list the category in the correct alpha location? 

When you display a category, such as 'apple', should that text be a link to the posts in that category? 

You mention category archive, so are you looking to list each post related to that category?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve a list of your categories using the `get_categories()` function.  You can pass an array of parameters to the function that will allow you to specify what sort order you would like used, among other things.

It should look something like this:

```
$defaults = array('type' => 'post',
    'child_of' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'include_last_update_time' => false,
    'hierarchical' => 1, 
    'exclude' => ,
    'include' => ,
    'number' => ,
    'pad_counts' => false
);

$categories = get_categories($defaults);
```

For more information on parameter values and using the returned categories, check out [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) in the Wordpress codex.